# Call Razor method from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I wrote a function inside my  razor view to check whether session exists or not

```
@functions {
   public static bool CheckSession()
   {
     return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] == null;
   }
}
```

Now what i do is that i want to check in ajax beforesend that session exists or not . if not exists then redirect user to login

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var isSession = '@CheckSession()';
    }
});
```

but issue is that in beforesend event i want to re-evaluate it every time .

Comment: What issue you are facing in evaluating?

Comment: it evaluate only once at page loading

Answer (score 0):

You can not implement it like this. The Code within @{} block is evaluated by razor engine at server side before returning html response. You have to make server side call in any case to re-evaluate the method.

You can do this by two method-

1) Always make separate ajax call to check session. But this is bad.

Second and better solution will be

2) You can decorate your controller/action with your custom attribute.Then check for session validity in that attribute and return particular response. Check for response value in ajax success call back and redirect to login page.